# How to cancel the effect by the option of raster style on nested tcbitemize enviroment

Tags: tcolorbox

I construct a raster by `tcbitemize` enviroment in `tcolorbox`. I found that the option `raster column 1/.style` have a effect on nested `tcbitemize` as shown in the following example. You can see that the first column of the nested raster is colored with red which is not what I want. How to cancel this effect by lower layer on higher layer of `tcolorbox` raster?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,raster}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tcbitemize}[raster equal height=rows,raster columns=4,raster column 1/.style={colback=red}]
        \tcbitem 1\tcbitem 1\tcbitem 1\tcbitem 1
        \tcbitem 1
        \tcbitem \begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=2]
                    \tcbitem 2\tcbitem 2
                \end{tcbitemize}
        \tcbitem 1\tcbitem 1    
    \end{tcbitemize}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want `\begin{tcbitemize}[empty,raster columns=2]`? This adds the `empty` skin.

Comment: What do you want the nested environment to look like? Without the column 1 settings but with what?

Comment: As you see, I just want the nested tcbitemize is not affected by its outer tcbitemize options. In my example, cells of the first column in the nested raster should not be colored with red.

Comment: Using the `breakable` library in conjunction with nested boxes is rather useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `raster columns 1` etc. styles are sticky and persist for the nested boxes as well unless explicitly defined again in a lower layer. Unfortunately neither the `reset` nor the `raster reset` option removes those styles.

```
\colorlet{standardbackground}{yellow}
\tcbset{layerone/.style={raster every box/.style={colback={standardbackground}},raster equal height=rows,raster columns=4,raster column 1/.style={colback=red}}}
\tcbset{layertwo/.style={raster columns=2,raster column 1/.style={colback=standardbackground}}}
```

define the standard background colour (`yellow` just for demonstration here) and clear all boxes to this background first, then set the specific settings for the first layer with and the first column to `colback=red` and redefine the settings for `raster column 1` to switch back to the standard background colour.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\colorlet{standardbackground}{yellow}

\tcbset{layerone/.style={raster every box/.style={colback={standardbackground}},raster equal height=rows,raster columns=4,raster column 1/.style={colback=red}}}
\tcbset{layertwo/.style={raster columns=2,raster column 1/.style={colback=standardbackground}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{tcbitemize}[layerone]
  \tcbitem 1\tcbitem 1\tcbitem 1\tcbitem 1
  \tcbitem 1
  \tcbitem 
  \begin{tcbitemize}[layertwo]
    \tcbitem 2\tcbitem 2
  \end{tcbitemize}
  \tcbitem 1\tcbitem 1    
\end{tcbitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why must \makeatother be used?

Comment: @lyl: The `\makeatother` command is a relic of a trial of solution -- I just forgot to remove it.

Comment: @lyl: I have answered your question, please consider to accept the answer, also for answers to other questions from other users or me in order to appreciate the work done in order to help you

Comment: I'm so sorry for delaying giving my response because I just have  chance to review my question. Thank you so much for your help in which I get a lot.